# Could not add 'LoginLogout' link using BAW login logout plugin

Tags: plugins, functions

I installed and activated the 'BAW login/logout' plugin to bring login or logout link in my screen. but this is not working for me. can some one help me

steps I followed:
1) Installed and activated'BAW Login/logout'plugin
2) In Menu panel I selected the value 'Login/Logout' and clicked on 'Add to Menu'
3) The 'Login/Logout' option is added to Menu structure
4) I saved the menu
5) I refreshed the website. But could not find the link 'Login' or 'Logout'

Comment: Did you read the [plugin FAQ](http://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-login-logout-menu/faq/)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing your custom link just by checking if user is logged in? you can do this using bult in wp functions

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href="'.wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Logout" class="hunderline">Logout</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="'.wp_login_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Login" class="hunderline">Login</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I can see login/logout in the widgets but not as a link on the top right corner of the screen.  I want to view this across all the pages.

Comment: you probably need to edit your header.php template